# Splitting string and getting what is between single quotes?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string `'1','name','phone','address, street'`
I want to split it in an array, so i am using :
`$link =~ s/'//g;` to remove "'" and then `@array = $link.split(',')`, the problem now is with address, as you can see here, the address might have a comma, so when splitting i get things wrong, I was thinking on doing a regex since the beginning but i dont know exactly how to write it, I mean this is what i could come up with `(?:.*?){1}[^']*[,](.*?)(?='|$)` but it doesn't work. ({1} varies from 1 to 5)

Comment: Why not split on `','` instead? Then you simply need to strip the `'` from the first and last items in the array?

Comment: it is like i said, `'address, street'` is one, when splitting on ',' it does split it too :/

Comment: use a dedicated CSV parser like `Text::CSV`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit more light-weight than [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) is [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords), which handles embedded delimiters, and also has the benefit of being a core module.

```
use Text::ParseWords;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str  = "'1','name','phone','address, street'";
my @list = quotewords(",", 0, $str);
print Dumper \@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          'name',
          'phone',
          'address, street'
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't use a regex for this; you use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV):

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ escape_char => "'", quote_char => "'", binary => 1 });

my $link = "'1','name','phone','address, street'";
$csv->parse($link) or die $csv->error_diag;
my @array = $csv->fields;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have never used Text::CSV before, but it does solve another problem i have too, Really helpful, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
','|'
```

for your regex

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate, split on the quote-comma-quote, not just the comma.

```
$link = "'1','name','phone','address, street'";
$link =~ s/(^'|'$)//g;
@array = split("','", $link);
print join("\n", @array);
```

Comment: Ah yes yes now i get it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just ignore the commas:

```
@array = /'([^']*)'/g;
```

This assumes that all entries are single-quoted, and contain no (escaped) single quotes.